Issue implementing Micronaut JWT
I'm trying to implement the follow the Micronaut guide at https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-security-jwt-maven-java.html
When I get to https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-security-jwt-maven-java.html#use-the-micronaut-http-client-and-jwt, my tests all fail.
My client is
package eco.aem.elements.stationcatalog;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Consumes;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import io.micronaut.security.token.render.BearerAccessRefreshToken;

import static io.micronaut.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static io.micronaut.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;

@Client("/")
public interface AppClient {

    @Post("/login")
    BearerAccessRefreshToken login(@Body UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials);

    @Consumes(TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Get
    String home(@Header(AUTHORIZATION) String authorization);
}

and my test is
package eco.aem.elements.stationcatalog;

import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.SignedJWT;
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import io.micronaut.security.token.render.BearerAccessRefreshToken;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.text.ParseException;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertInstanceOf;

@MicronautTest
class DeclarativeHttpClientWithJwtTest {

    @Inject
    AppClient appClient;

    @Test
    void verifyJwtAuthenticationWorksWithDeclarativeClient() throws ParseException {
        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("sherlock", "password");
        BearerAccessRefreshToken loginRsp = appClient.login(creds);

        assertNotNull(loginRsp);
        assertNotNull(loginRsp.getAccessToken());
        assertInstanceOf(SignedJWT.class, JWTParser.parse(loginRsp.getAccessToken()));
        System.out.println(loginRsp.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println(loginRsp.getUsername());
        String msg = appClient.home("Bearer " + loginRsp.getAccessToken());
        assertEquals("sherlock", msg);
    }
}

When I run the test, I get
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Forbidden
When the code executes
String msg = appClient.home("Bearer " + loginRsp.getAccessToken());
What am I missing here?  I've looked over this code over and over and I'm not seeing what the issue is.

There is a link to the complete code in that guide. I just verified that all tests in that code are passing. I also pasted code from your question into the downloaded code, and tests are still passing. I believe the problem is in code/settings not shown in your question. BR
